# Postgres SQL: INSERT from DELETE

Tags: postgresql, insert, delete, syntax

I have a table with `id,user_id,timestamp` and I'm trying to `INSERT` into the table, the `user_id` from a `DELETE from table where id=some_number` and `timestamp`. So what I'm trying to achieve looks like:

```
INSERT INTO table (user_id,timestamp)
VALUES (
    (DELETE FROM table WHERE id=some_number returning user_id),
    current_timestamp+'1 day'
)
RETURNING *;
```

I am getting a syntax error doing this... Can someone help me here plz...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [data modifying common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with deleted as (
  DELETE FROM some_table
  WHERE id = 42
  returning user_id
)
INSERT INTO other_table(user_id, "timestamp")
select user_id, timestamp '2020-01-04 21:32:34'
from deleted;
```

Comment: So, I'm trying to extract only user_id from the DELETE and a separate some_timestamp value. (Edited the question just now.)

Comment: @GhanashyamS: see my edit

Comment: Any way I can achieve this...?
`timestamp (current_timestamp+'1 day')`

Comment: `current_timestamp + interval '1 day'` will work

Comment: Perfect! Again! Thank you!!